# Display a loading overlay on Android screen

Tags: android, progress-bar, overlay

I'm looking to display an overlay over the screen that shows a little loading ticker or possibly even some text whilst my app attempts to log into the server. My login screen is all inside of a vertical linear layout.

The effect I'm trying to achieve is something like this: http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/popovers/display_a_loading_message

Comment: You are looking for this ? right ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android

Comment: @M-WaJeEh How do I add text and/or graphics to that activity?

Comment: like you add to a normal `Activity`. Its just a normal `Activity` with different theme.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Maybe too late, but I guess somebody might find it useful.

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    String myLog = "myLog";

    AlphaAnimation inAnimation;
    AlphaAnimation outAnimation;

    FrameLayout progressBarHolder;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        progressBarHolder = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.progressBarHolder);

        button.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button:
                new MyTask().execute();
                break;
        }

    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            button.setEnabled(false);
            inAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0f, 1f);
            inAnimation.setDuration(200);
            progressBarHolder.setAnimation(inAnimation);
            progressBarHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            outAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1f, 0f);
            outAnimation.setDuration(200);
            progressBarHolder.setAnimation(outAnimation);
            progressBarHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            button.setEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    Log.d(myLog, "Emulating some task.. Step " + i);
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start doing stuff"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Do Some Stuff"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/progressBarHolder"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:alpha="0.4"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This should be selected as the answer imo. The selected answer suggests about ProgressDialog which isn't commonly used anymore and provides no code.

Comment: spend all my day finding out how to do it m really thank you

Comment: Used the same code it's working but the activity content is not visible at all behind the semi-transparent layer it's totally semi-black is this the correct result or i'm doing something wrong?

Comment: this is great, but is there a way to disable all the content of the activity while the loader is spinning? Separately enabling and disabling all editTexts seems like a lot of work!

Answer (score 82):

I like the approach in [Kostya But's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24471803/56285).

Building on that, here's a couple of ideas to make the same overlay easily **reusable** across your app:

Consider putting the overlay FrameLayout in a separate layout file, e.g. `res/layout/include_progress_overlay`:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/progress_overlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.4"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminate="true"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

(One thing I added in the overlay FrameLayout is `android:clickable="true"`. So while the overlay is shown, it prevents clicks going through to UI elements underneath it. At least in my typical use cases this is what I want.)

Then include it where needed:

```
<!-- Progress bar overlay; shown while login is in progress -->
<include layout="@layout/include_progress_overlay"/>
```

And in code:

```
View progressOverlay;
[...]

progressOverlay = findViewById(R.id.progress_overlay);
[...]

// Show progress overlay (with animation): 
AndroidUtils.animateView(progressOverlay, View.VISIBLE, 0.4f, 200);
[...]

// Hide it (with animation): 
AndroidUtils.animateView(progressOverlay, View.GONE, 0, 200);
```

With animation code extracted into a util method:

```
/**
 * @param view         View to animate
 * @param toVisibility Visibility at the end of animation
 * @param toAlpha      Alpha at the end of animation
 * @param duration     Animation duration in ms
 */
public static void animateView(final View view, final int toVisibility, float toAlpha, int duration) {
    boolean show = toVisibility == View.VISIBLE;
    if (show) {
        view.setAlpha(0);
    }
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    view.animate()
            .setDuration(duration)
            .alpha(show ? toAlpha : 0)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            view.setVisibility(toVisibility);
        }
    });
}
```

(Here using `view.animate()`, added in API 12, instead of `AlphaAnimation`.)

Comment: I'm using a ConstraintLayout and had to use `progressOverlay.bringToFront()` to prevent interaction with other UI elements. Otherwise, neat answer Jonik and Kostya.

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setAlpha(float)' on a null object reference

Comment: @AnantaPrasad I have the same problem. Did you fix it?

Comment: To fix the null reference, make sure this `progressOverlay = findViewById(R.id.progress_overlay);` is after `setContentView`

Comment: Thanks for this idea, I implemented a similar solution, however I needed to add an elevation to the FrameLayout to avoid buttons being placed above and then becoming clickable.  ```android:elevation="10dp"``` worked for me

Comment: remove focus from elements behind the overlay set property android:clickable="true" and android:elevation="10dp"  and android:focusable="true" in the  framelayout

Answer (score 5):

I have ProgressBar in Relative Layout and I hide or show it respectively. And yes activity can be transparent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/hsvBackgroundContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    </LinearLayout>


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbProgess"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Using a relative layout instead of the standard layout android uses for logins was the solution to my problem, that I wasn't able to center the progress bar. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

A spinner with a message over the application can be created using a ProgressDialog. Whilst it doesn't achieve the exact effect as in the picture, it's a good way to show that the app is working.

Comment: I realize this is an old answer, but for anyone finding this in 2020, ProgressDialog is now deprecated: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog

Answer (score 2):

I made a [library](https://github.com/Gkemon/Lovely-Android-Loading) (*Not well documented yet, Do it within a few days after reducing some work pressure*) to do this kind of **progress dialog**. I made it the very **reusable** way that's why you need to just configure it one time and hide show it anywhere in your app just calling a single line of code. The **configuration** -

```
 LoadingPopup.getInstance(this)
                .customLoading()
               .setCustomViewID(R.layout.yourProgressLayout,R.color.yourProgressBackgroundColor)
                .doIntentionalDelay()
                .setDelayDurationInMillSec(5000)
                .setBackgroundOpacity(70)/*How much transparent you want your background*/
                .build();
```

For showing the progress -

```
LoadingPopup.showLoadingPopUp();
```

For hiding the progress-

```
LoadingPopup.hideLoadingPopUp();
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question, I tried the solutions but was not the best UI so, I did the followings steps.

1. Divide the screen in 2 views: Content and ProgressBar.
2. When you want to call the ProgressBar you change the visibility to VISIBLE and add the following properties to the content id=content and not to the progressBar container.

content.background="#000000"
content.alpha="0.4"

```
<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Start doing stuff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Do Some Stuff"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to make a background operation using thread concept like AsyncTask. Using this you can hide the actual work from the UI part. And AsyncTask will get unallocated after your operations are completed.

- Create a subclass of AsyncTask
- Use AsyncTask to do background work
- Call onPreExecute() to initialize task
- Use a progressbar with setIndeterminate(true) to enable the
  indeterminate mode
- Call onProgressUpdate() to animate your progressbar to let the user
  know some work is being done
- Use incrementProgressBy() for increment progressbar content by a
  specific value
- Call doInBackground()and do the background work here
- Catch an InterruptedException object to find end of background
  operation
- Call onPostExecute() to denote the end of operation and show the
  result

[Android's indeterminate ProgressDialog tutorial](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/android-app-builder/androids-indeterminate-progressdialog-tutorial/)

[Splash screen while loading resources in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018069/splash-screen-while-loading-resources-in-android-app)