# How many AsyncTasks i can run in an single process application

Tags: android, android-asynctask, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I am using asyncTasks, to load list elements with images (Just followed android's tutorial of efficiently loading bitmaps)

In DDMS, i can see upto 5 AsyncTasks being running

Now in addition i have added another AsyncTask, which performs some decoding using MediaCodec class.

Now in DDMS, i still see 5 AsyncTasks, and my image loading aynctask or decoding async task executes, not both of them.

When decoding is running, if i scroll the list, elements' images are not updated
Counterly when i launch new decoding asynctask by calling it's execute method, the decoding doesn't start, but if i scroll the list view now, the images are updated.

So is AsyncTask is limitted??

Even in listAdapter i launch an AsyncTask per getView call. I'd expecting 7 running asyncTasks (if list visible elements are 7, say), but DDMS shows only 5 asynctasks running.

Now can someone explain me what's the black magic that i can't spell?

Comment: Answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654148/android-asynctask-threads-limits/9654445#9654445

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**How many `AsyncTasks` can you run at once?**

In most versions of Android, the answer is **128**.

**Why will you generally see exactly 5 `AsyncTask` threads?**

`AsyncTask` thread management is rather confusing, especially since it has changed a lot since the first Android release.

In newer Android versions, 5 threads are create by default, and the `ThreadPoolExecutor` will attempt to run the `AsyncTask`s on these 5 threads. If you create more than 5 `AsyncTask`s, it may either queue them or create new threads (but only up to 128).

Note that in earlier versions of Android, these limits were differently. I believe that, originally, there was only ever one thread created.

**But all your images should load eventually...**

To answer the other part of your question, unless you're loading a lot of images (where a lot means >128), all the images should load, although likely sequentially. If the first 5 load and the rest do not, that might indicate that your `doInBackground()` function is never finishing or there is something else wrong with the `AsyncTask` you are using.

**Resources:**

Here are some helpful resources for learning more about `AsyncTask` thread management:

[AsyncTask threads never die](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077461/asynctask-threads-never-die-android)

[Android AsyncTask threads limits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654148/android-asynctask-threads-limits)

[Is there a limit of AsyncTasks to be executed at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593850/is-there-a-limit-of-asynctasks-to-be-executed-at-the-same-time)

Comment: All my images are loading. One more doubt, Cancelled AsyncTasks,will it count to number of AsyncTasks? i.e, counted in core thread count or maximum thread count?

Comment: Once a `AsyncTask` ends, it would not count towards the 128, I believe. However, even if you have less than 5 `AsyncTask`s remaining, you will likely still see 5 threads. (See the first link above.)

Comment: Excellent Answer.