# How many AsyncTasks can you execute in parallel?

Tags: java, android

AsyncTask are executed seriallu but we can execute them parallely using executeOnExecutor. How many Asynctask we can execute parallely in Android?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many AsyncTasks i can run in an single process application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24505981/how-many-asynctasks-i-can-run-in-an-single-process-application)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this StackOverflow post has already answered your question: [How many AsyncTasks i can run in an single process application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24505981/how-many-asynctasks-i-can-run-in-an-single-process-application)

> **How many AsyncTasks can you run at once?**
>
> In most versions of Android, the answer is 128.

Please do a quick search before asking these questions.

Answer (score 0):

Android uses ThreadPool inside AsyncTask. Maximum size of this thread pool is

```
MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = CPU_COUNT * 2 + 1;
```

So maximum number of AysncTask depends on CPU Count.

Reference:

> http://dsalgos.com/971/how-many-asynctasks-can-you-execute-in-parallel

Comment: Adding to this, you can also create your own executor, with your own settings. So with a custom executor, it can be theoretically unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer.

> AsyncTask uses a thread pool pattern for running the stuff from
>   doInBackground(). The issue is initially (in early Android OS
>   versions) the pool size was just 1, meaning no parallel computations
>   for a bunch of AsyncTasks. But later they fixed that and now the size
>   is 5, so at most 5 AsyncTasks can run simultaneously. Unfortunately I
>   don't remember in what version exactly they changed that.

[Running multiple AsyncTasks at the same time -- not possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible)

Also check the above link. Hope it will help.