# Cannot run more than two asynctask concurrently

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, threadpoolexecutor

When I run multiple `AsyncTasks` in my view using  `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` flag I found that no more than two `AsyncTasks` running concurrently. Actually when two `AsyncTasks` complete their work next two get started. I also try this `AsyncTask` test project in [github](https://github.com/vitkhudenko/test_asynctask). I got a same result, looking at logcat there where no more two `AsyncTasks` running concurrently.

How can I run more than two asynctasks concurrently?

Comment: @blackbelt Do you have a sample code or a useful link?

Comment: for the Executor? Take a look to the documentation :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593850/is-there-a-limit-of-asynctasks-to-be-executed-at-the-same-time

Comment: @SamJ I tried that github project.

Comment: @Pavlos The link says: AsyncTask is backed by a ThreadPoolExecutor with a core pool size of 5, but a maximum pool size of 128 (from 1.6 - 4.0.3). I got confused why I can't have 4 AsyncTasks at the same time!

Comment: @blackbelt Yeah, the problem is solved. Executor is the solution. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) says:

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single
>   background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of
>   threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with
>   HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common
>   application errors caused by parallel execution.

So that means that they are executed on a single thread, meaning, by default, you can only have **one** `AsyncTask` active at a time.

But, fear not, the documentation further states:

> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke
>   executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with
>   THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

So... `new MyTask().executeOnExecutor( AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR );`

will do the trick for you.