# How many async task can be used in a class android?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, asynchronous

Recently I attended an interview in which I was asked a question: How many asynctask can be used in a class? By using execute method you will use by calling asynctask. So maximum limit of asynctask in a class is the question thrown to me.

What is the answer for this? Can someone please explain how many and why?

Comment: It can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593850/is-there-a-limit-of-asynctasks-to-be-executed-at-the-same-time

Comment: Also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654148/android-asynctask-threads-limits

Comment: And more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654148/android-asynctask-threads-limits

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question itself does not make any sense. You can use as many `AsyncTask` in a class as you want, if there were a restriction on that it would be ridiculous. I assume he meant how many `AsyncTask` can be executed at the same time and how they are executed and the answer to that would be: It depends.

`AsyncTasks` can be executed either in series or in parallel. The default behaviour depends on the API level of the device. The [**documentation**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute(Params...)) of `execute()` of `AsyncTask` says:

> Note: this function schedules the task on a queue for a single
>   background thread or pool of threads depending on the platform
>   version. When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a
>   single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a
>   pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel.
>   Starting HONEYCOMB, tasks are back to being executed on a single
>   thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel
>   execution. If you truly want parallel execution, you can use the
>   executeOnExecutor(Executor, Params...) version of this method with
>   THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR; however, see commentary there for warnings on
>   its use.

Having said that you can choose whether you want to execute them in parallel or in series like this:

```
// Executes the task in parallel to other tasks
asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

// Adds the task to a queue and executes one at a time.
asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
```

However even if you run the tasks in parallel there is a limit to how many can run at the same time. To find out where that limit is you have to look into the [**source code of AsyncTask**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/os/AsyncTask.java/).

Up until Android 4.3 (Jelly Bean) the limits were hardcoded to those values:

```
private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = 5;
private static final int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = 128;
private static final int KEEP_ALIVE = 1;
```

But with Android 4.4 that was changed and the limits are calculated depending on the used processor in the device:

```
private static final int CPU_COUNT = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = CPU_COUNT + 1;
private static final int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = CPU_COUNT * 2 + 1;
private static final int KEEP_ALIVE = 1;
```

The implementation of the `ThreadPoolExecutor` remained the same in both cases:

```
public static final Executor THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR
        = new ThreadPoolExecutor(CORE_POOL_SIZE, MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE, KEEP_ALIVE,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS, sPoolWorkQueue, sThreadFactory);
```

So that should pretty much answer your question. But if you really want to find out how the `AsyncTask` works then you should study the source code yourself! [**This link leads to the AsyncTask implementation on Android 4.4**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/os/AsyncTask.java/).