# The maximum number AsyncTask's of an Android application

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In the Android application from the Application-class will start a few singletons, each with a few AsyncTask's. In this case, it will simultaneously run a maximum of 5 or 128 AsyncTask's? SDK>16

Comment: Your question is not clear at all

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Thare can only be so many *simultaneously* running threads as you have cores in your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

[How many async task can be used in a class android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26075422/how-many-async-task-can-be-used-in-a-class-android) check this thread, I think it would be useful. 
Summary - you can run as much as you want, but they would execute parallel or serial after some point (when all threads would be used). And it depends on device.

Answer (score 0):

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.

Based on the description above, I assumed that starting from API 11, all tasks will be executed in serial execution on a single thread, meaning that one at a time, unless we call `AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);` on every tasks we execute, but still the number of tasks can be run at a time is still depends on resources at that time, e.g. number of cores are free to processing.