# RejectedExecutionException in Android Studio

Tags: android, sdk, navigation, here-api

My app (using HERE Android SDK) crashes while doing the simulated turn-by-turn navigation, the exception log is as below, please tell how to resolve it.

> device model:SM-G9008V
>   SDK:5.0-----------java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException:
>   Task android.os.AsyncTask$3@36d584c9 rejected from
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@23d4f7ce[Running, pool size =
>   9, active threads = 9, queued tasks = 128, completed tasks = 828]
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2011)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:793)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1339)
>       android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:590)
>       com.nokia.maps.bf.c(LocationRestHandler.java:207)
>       com.nokia.maps.bf.b(LocationRestHandler.java:198)
>       com.nokia.maps.dn.b(PlacesReverseGeocodeRequest.java:256)
>       com.nokia.maps.dn.a(PlacesReverseGeocodeRequest.java:28)
>       com.nokia.maps.dn$1.run(PlacesReverseGeocodeRequest.java:104)
>       android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>       android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>       android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>       android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
>       java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>       com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
>       com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8183463/3410697

Answer (score 2):

Are you issuing many requests concurrently? It seems you have issued too many requests and exceeded the maximum number outstanding:

java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@23d4f7ce[Running, pool size = 9, active threads = 9, queued tasks = 128, completed tasks = 828]

What are you doing in the navigation code? Can you post a snippet?

Answer (score 1):

> Why would I be getting this error message?

You would get this error message if you have exceeded the number of tasks that can be queued by the `ThreadPoolExecutor`. The only time the `RejectedExecutionException` is thrown is by the `ThreadPoolExecutor`.AbortPolicy which is the default `RejectedExecutionHandler`.

To quote from the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html):

> If a request cannot be queued, a new thread is created unless this
>   would exceed maximumPoolSize, in which case, the task will be
>   rejected.

There is a maximum number of tasks. See this question/answer here: [Is there a limit of AsyncTasks to be executed at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593850/is-there-a-limit-of-asynctasks-to-be-executed-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 0):

@David, below is the code snippet:

```
if(navigationManager == null) {
            navigationManager = NavigationManager.getInstance();
            navigationManager.setMap(map);
        }

        // start listening to navigation events
        instructListener = new InstructListener();
        navigationManager.addNewInstructionEventListener(
                new WeakReference<NavigationManager.NewInstructionEventListener>(instructListener));

        // start listening to position events
        if (naviPositionListener == null) {
            naviPositionListener = new NaviPositionListener();
        }
        navigationManager.addPositionListener(
                new WeakReference<NavigationManager.PositionListener>(naviPositionListener));

        if (maneuverEventListener == null) {
            maneuverEventListener = new ManeuverEventListener();
        }
        navigationManager.addManeuverEventListener(
                new WeakReference<NavigationManager.ManeuverEventListener>(maneuverEventListener));


        if (myNavigationManagerEventListener == null) {
            myNavigationManagerEventListener = new MyNavigationManagerEventListener();
        }
        navigationManager.addNavigationManagerEventListener(new WeakReference<NavigationManager.NavigationManagerEventListener>(myNavigationManagerEventListener));

        if (rerouteListener == null) {
            rerouteListener = new MyRerouteListener();
        }
        navigationManager.addRerouteListener(new WeakReference<RerouteListener>(rerouteListener));

        if (safetySpotListener == null) {
            safetySpotListener = new MySafetySpotListener();
        }
        navigationManager.addSafetySpotListener(new WeakReference<NavigationManager.SafetySpotListener>(safetySpotListener));

        //add realistic view listener
        navigationManager.setRealisticViewMode(NavigationManager.RealisticViewMode.DAY);
        navigationManager.addRealisticViewAspectRatio(NavigationManager.AspectRatio.AR_4x3);

        if (realisticViewListener == null) {
            realisticViewListener = new MyRealisticViewListener();
        }
        navigationManager.addRealisticViewListener(
                new WeakReference<NavigationManager.RealisticViewListener>(realisticViewListener));


        //set map udpate mode
        navigationManager.setMapUpdateMode(NavigationManager.MapUpdateMode.ROADVIEW);
        navigationManager.setTrafficAvoidanceMode(NavigationManager.TrafficAvoidanceMode.DISABLE);

        //set natural guidance mode
        EnumSet<NavigationManager.NaturalGuidanceMode> modeset = navigationManager.getNaturalGuidanceMode();
        modeset.add(NavigationManager.NaturalGuidanceMode.TRAFFIC_LIGHT);
        modeset.add(NavigationManager.NaturalGuidanceMode.STOP_SIGN);
        modeset.add(NavigationManager.NaturalGuidanceMode.JUNCTION);

        navigationManager.setNaturalGuidanceMode(modeset);

        // add gps signal listener
        if (gpsSignalListener == null) {
            gpsSignalListener = new MyGpsSignalListener();
        }
        navigationManager.addGpsSignalListener(new WeakReference<NavigationManager.GpsSignalListener>(gpsSignalListener));


        if (speedWarningListener == null) {
            speedWarningListener = new MySpeedWarningListener();
        }
        navigationManager.addSpeedWarningListener(new WeakReference<NavigationManager.SpeedWarningListener>(speedWarningListener));

        //add lane info listener
        if (laneInfoListener == null) {
            laneInfoListener = new MyLaneInfoListener();
        }
        navigationManager.addLaneInfoListener(new WeakReference<NavigationManager.LaneInfoListener>(laneInfoListener));


        navigationManager.getRoadView().setOrientation(NavigationManager.RoadView.Orientation.DYNAMIC);
        navigationManager.getRoadView().addListener(new WeakReference<NavigationManager.RoadView.Listener>(roadViewListener));


        //start navigation
        long speed = 60; // meter per second
    navigationManager.simulate(mapRoute.getRoute(), speed);
```

Comment: This code isn't issuing any requests, so it cannot be contributing to the problem.

Comment: @David, I'm not sure which kind of request, can you please provide a example? What we have done during navigation are adding navigation listeners and start navigation.

Comment: Geocoding, place search would internally have uses for async tasks. Are you somehow issuing lookups continuously? 

Or alternatively, does your app use many async tasks? Perhaps a systrace of your application will show what the async task threads are doing?

Comment: Thanks David, we found the issue, it was caused by too many unnecessary geocoding searching requests in our codes as what you said.