# Why do I need a Looper in my AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, handler, looper

I want to use AsyncTask for update my db4o with a server. In the doInBackground method , I connect to the server, update the db4o, and schedule a pendingintents. Not modify UI or show any toast.

Initially, I had the following error:

```
Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

After adding the Looper.prepare(), works fine, but only for five updates (AsyncTask). I've read this topic: [AsyncTask threads never die (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077461/asynctask-threads-never-die-android) , and I don't now that fails. When I throw the sixth update, the app crashes:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread
at android.os.Looper.prepare(Looper.java:74)
(...)
```

[image: five AsyncTask]

I've read in the documentation that I need the Looper.loop(), but whith this, the app crashes..

Example:

```
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Looper.prepare();

        update = new Update();
        update.checknewObjects();
        update.deleteOldObjects();
        update.updateObjects();
        Looper.loop();
}
```

Why do I need Looper?
Why the app crashes after five updates?
Where can I schedule Looper.loop()?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread" check if you are not using Looper more then one time on the same thread. Generally a Looper is needed if you are using Handlers inside threads (the main app thread has a Looper).
http://mindtherobot.com/blog/159/android-guts-intro-to-loopers-and-handlers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `AsyncTask` so use it, you shouldn't mix it with `Lopper`...

```
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {}
```

already working on background thread and there is no reason to call Lopper, for what?

If your application need to do some kind of long computation so `AsyncTask` is very good tool for it because offers methods which working on `UI Thread` and allow to update `UI` with some progress of work because every User that will use your application should know that application "doing something" (when it takes more than 2-5 seconds).

Also it's generic and that provide some benefits.

If you do not need to update `UI` just use for example `Handler`.

Comment: Thanks deceiver.. but.. If Idon't use the looper I've the following error: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: Your error means that you are trying to update your `UI` from background thread. this is generally not allowed.

Comment: Looper can be used effectively in AsyncTask as well, in case u r using AsyncTask#executeOnExecutor() instead of #execute(), it puts your thread in another thread pool, which uses a different Handler AKA Looper.  so u have to call Looper.prepare()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to schedule tasks you should use Timer & TimerTask, from what I understand I think they should fit better to your needs.
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Answer (score 0):

in  asynck Task you can't use looping  in background function .it giving error