# Why does AsyncTasks not get destroyed in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my app, I continuously create an AsyncTask about every 5 seconds. I have inspected the task during debug and can clearly see that the task always completes its process and exits the doInBackground method. No code in the onPostExecute is ever executed. Yet the AsyncTask continues to remain in memory as I can see in Eclipse. I thought that maybe it would just get reused for the next loop or eventually garbage collected but another one gets created and this continues. Eventually enough of them get created and slows the system down.

What could be the potential problem?

Comment: As long as `doInBackground()` returns in a finite time, that would not be a problem, and that thread would be recycled for future tasks.

Comment: Have you tried to debug single Async task at a time or switch between threads from debug perspective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AsyncTask manages a thread pool, created with ThreadPoolExecutor. It
>   will have from 5 to 128 threads. If there are more than 5 threads,
>   those extra threads will stick around for at most 10 seconds before
>   being removed. (note: these figures are for the presently-visible open
>   source code and vary by Android release).
>
> Leave the AsyncTask threads alone, please

Source question: [AsyncTask threads never die](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077461/asynctask-threads-never-die-android)